# Set formNameGroup value inside directive

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I'm using reactive forms. Inside my directive I have access to the element thanks to `ElementRef.

However when I try to set the value of my textarea element using `this.element.nativeElement.value = 'new text'` the value doesn't get updated and the formGroupName doesn't trigger any `changeValues`.

How can I properly set the value of a textarea element that uses `formGroupName`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need to dispatch the event when changing the value this way. It doesn't automatically get dispatched. This is how the directive knows that value has changed; by listening for the input event.

```
this.element.nativeElement.value = 'new text'
this.element.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
```